# Proving a language is context free by coming up with a context free grammar for the language

Tags: computation-models

Let A and B be languages over $\sum$ = {0, 1, 2, 3}

Language A = {$(0U1)^a(1U2)^b(2U3)^c | a \geq  b$}

Language B = {$(0U1)^a(1U2)^b(2U3)^c | a = c$}

Question: prove that A and B are context free

Comment: You asked a very closely related question here: http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/22891/755.  What's up with that?

Comment: This is a dump of an exercise problem, not a question. If you have a specific question regarding the wording of the problem or concrete steps in your own attempts at solving the problem, feel free to edit accordingly and we can reopen the question. See also [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/a/470/) for our homework policy, and [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/594) for a relevant discussion. You may also want to check out our [reference questions](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/599/). If you are uncertain how to improve your question, why not ask around in [chat]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The grammar for language B appears correct. But the grammar for language A is incorrect. This grammar will produce strings that are out of order and not in the language. Try:

$S\rightarrow AB$

$A\rightarrow (0U1)A|(0U1)A(1U2)|\epsilon$

$B\rightarrow (2U3)B|\epsilon$

My idea was to break it up into two sections and just deal with those.

Comment: thanks for the answer, can you look at the CFG for A again? I edited my post. I believe it is correct now

Comment: It is very close to correct but you are missing the case when $a=0$, $b=0$ but $c>0$. I also don't think the rule $T\rightarrow AATB$ is necessary since you have $B\rightarrow \epsilon$.

Comment: alright, thanks. I think I fixed it now -- can you look at the edit to my post

Comment: Looks good, you can even reduce $S\rightarrow ATBC$ to just $S\rightarrow TC$; but it is still correct  without doing this.

Comment: is it ok that there are parentheses and unions in the terminals? A and B are languages over the alphabet {0,1,2,3}

Comment: I actually didn't notice that before. You can use \cup in latex for the union symbol. But let me think about it for a little and get back to you.